# Pandas Str Regex Replace Characters Except for Word

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a Pandas DataFrame column with values like the following:

| Name |
| --- |
| PIZZA NAME HERE ZZ HELLO |
| HELLO ZZZZZZZ WORLD |

I'd like to identify all instances of two or more Z's, without identifying a certain word, PIZZA in this case. I'd use `.str.replace(regex,"")` to replace it with whitespace afterwards. The final result would look like:

| Name |
| --- |
| PIZZA NAME HERE HELLO |
| HELLO WORLD |

Not the best at understanding Regex, but the following doesn't work for me like I thought it would since it still detects the ZZ in PIZZA.

```
^((?!.*PIZZA.*).)*$|Z{2,}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using word boundary markers instead such as with this pattern `\bZ{2,}\b`. However, if you simply do `.str.replace(regex,"")` it will lead to a double space i.e. `PIZZA NAME HERE  HELLO`.

The simple fix for that is changing either the boundary markers with whitespace markers i.e. `\sZ{2,}\s`. This will remove both spaces and thus requires `.str.replace(regex," ")` instead, and also fail at the start and end of the string.

So to fix the start/end of string issue, we can combine the two methods with `(?:\s|\b)Z{2,}(?:\s|\b)`.

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/WJshnW/1)

Comment: I originally was going to use another regex to take care of double spaces, but I like your approach better. Thanks!